# Access Token Question in Azure Functions Authentication

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

I followed the link [Enable Azure Active Directory in your App Service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-enable-azure-active-directory-in-your-app-service-app) for setting up AAD authentication for my Azure Functions. For calling the Azure Functions, I tried using the token obtained as [First case: Access token request with a shared secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret), and I got error status 401 "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." This access token is from the Uri [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token). In testing I found if I request the token from the Uri [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/token), it works. Why is that?

The token from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) is decoded as follows.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "klkSaiUS7yT5KMshYVJZAkyu5AuDV14yEQLEkxiz2o4",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "huN95IvPfehq34GzBDZ1GXGirnM",
  "kid": "huN95IvPfehq34GzBDZ1GXGirnM"
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/",
  "iat": 1597615459,
  "nbf": 1597615459,
  "exp": 1597619359,
  "aio": "E2BgYOD6EGiutPFpxY67vVocPgv3AAA=",
  "app_displayname": "app Displayname",
  "appid": "{appId GUID}",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/",
  "oid": "{GUID}",
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Invite.All",
    "TeamMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "Team.ReadBasic.All",
    "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "{GUID}",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "{tenantId}",
  "uti": "lA__6UDggU6QYEGdX0t_AA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1590621751
}.[Signature]
```

The token from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/token) is decoded as follows.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "huN95IvPfehq34GzBDZ1GXGirnM",
  "kid": "huN95IvPfehq34GzBDZ1GXGirnM"
}.{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/",
  "iat": 1597615470,
  "nbf": 1597615470,
  "exp": 1597619370,
  "aio": "E2BgYOAS8fUOUly15/PahOer9u1iBQA=",
  "appid": "{appId GUID}",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/",
  "oid": "{GUID}",
  "sub": "{GUID}",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "{tenantId}",
  "uti": "3wr4Ulqcs0ueW77ZacF4AA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

I am aware that two tokens have different audiences, and have added both to "Allowed Token Audiences" in Azure Functions' AAD authentication.

Please help me to understand this. Really appreciate.